# Angular-Cdk-Drag-Drop getSortedItems is not instantly updated on drop event

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm using a drag and drop list for a user to arrange items in the proper order. The issue I'm having is that there currently is a `setTimeout` in my code because the method to retrieve the order of the list is not instantly updated on drop. I suspect it updates after the animation or something.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sort-order" cdkDropList *ngIf="parsedInteraction?.optionsSortOrder"
    [cdkDropListData]="parsedInteraction?.optionsSortOrder" (cdkDropListDropped)="sortOrderDrop($event)">
    <div class="sort-order-draggable" *ngFor="let item of parsedInteraction?.optionsSortOrder" cdkDrag
        [cdkDragData]="item">
        <div *ngIf="item?.picture" [innerHTML]="item.picture | safeHtml"></div>
        <div *ngIf="item?.option" [innerHTML]="item.option | safeHtml"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
sortOrderDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<InteractionOptionSortOrder[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex
  );

  // How to remove this ugly thing?
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.currentSortOrder = (
      event.container.getSortedItems() as CdkDrag<InteractionOptionSortOrder>[]
    )
      .map((draggable) => draggable.data.position)
      .join(',');
  }, 100);

  this.hasDragged = true;
}
```

How do I get rid of the timeout if I want to know the current sort order?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `event.container.data` holds the correct order after the `moveItemInArray` method. Still wondering why `getSortedItems` is delayed and how this is supposed to work.

```
moveItemInArray(
  event.container.data,
  event.previousIndex,
  event.currentIndex
);

this.currentSortOrder = event.container.data
  .map((draggable) => draggable.position)
  .join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex then just store that order in some variable before moveItemArray()